# Variable in Invoke-WebRequest -Uri path

Tags: powershell, invoke-webrequest

I am trying to pass a MAC Address and code (1,2,3,4) to `Invoke-WebRequest`.
Manually the command is working fine, but I am not able to do it via command.

The manual command that works is:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://mywebsite.org/pcconfig/setstate.php?mac=F832E3A2503B"&"state=4
```

Now when I break this up into variable to use with the mac from the machine I do the following.

```
$LiveMAC = Get-NetAdapter -Physical |
           where Status -eq "Up" |
           Select-Object -ExpandProperty PermanentAddress

$Str1 = "https://mywebsite.org/pcconfig/setstate.php?mac=$LiveMAC"
$Str2 = $Str1 + '"&"' + 'state=4'
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Str2
```

When I run the above code I do not see errors in red, it seems to process but does not work.

Looking at `$Str2` I see the below output, which seems correct, but when passing it as above it fails to work.

```
https://mywebsite.org/pcconfig/setstate.php?mac=F832E3A2503B"&"state=4
```

Answer (score 3):

The double quotes in a statement like

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://example.org/some/sit.php?foo=x"&"bar=y
```

mask the ampersand for *PowerShell*, because otherwise otherwise PowerShell would throw an error that a bare `&` is reserved for future use. A more canonical way of avoiding this is to put the entire URI in quotes:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://example.org/some/sit.php?foo=x&bar=y"
```

Either way the actual URI that is passed to `Invoke-WebRequest` is

```
https://example.org/some/sit.php?foo=x&bar=y
```

without the quotes.

However, in a code snippet like this:

```
$Str1 = "https://example.org/some/site.php?foo=$foo"
$Str2 = $Str1 + '"&"' + 'state=4'
```

you're including literal double quotes as part of the URI, so the actual URI passed to the cmdlet would be

```
https://example.org/some/sit.php?foo=x"&"bar=y
```

which is invalid.

With that said, you don't need string concatenation for building your URI anyway. Simply put your variable in the double-quoted string:

```
$uri = "https://example.org/some/sit.php?foo=${foo}&bar=y"
```

If you need to insert the value of an object property or array element use either a subexpression

```
$uri = "https://example.org/some/sit.php?foo=$($foo[2])&bar=y"
```

or the format operator

```
$uri = 'https://example.org/some/sit.php?foo={0}&bar=y' -f $foo[2]
```